# How do I pass XML data from MS Access to Server .ASPX Page in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, ms-access

So I have an MS Access program with VB Script loading data from Access Database.  I would like to pass this information to my server.  I would like the data to be transferred in XML.

On the Server side, I have a ASPX page setup to handle the incoming data.  How do I get data from MS Access to that ASPX page?

Comment: What kind of data do you mean, can't the ASPX just open the .mdb and read the data?

Comment: Normal object data.  The data is on the client's computer so I don't have access to it.

Comment: Nothing yet... just an empty string in C# waiting to be filled with XML.

Comment: Do you absolutely **have** to pass it to an ASPX page, can you use a hander or module and pass something like JSON (I thinking an AJAX style request).  Access is going to be a pretty significant limiting factor, you might even need to write an COM component in .NET and use it as an intermediary.

Comment: You need to clarify your question: Why XML? ASPX will do what - display data or persist data (again) somewhere? Although its not the best, you can expose MS access data by copying the mdb file to your server, and simply do queries against it and display results to web page.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to use a Web service to pass the data around. MS Access isn't really designed to use things like SOAP/ASMX, JSON, etc. You can install the Web Service Reference tool (link below). Since you have an ASPX page, we can assume you're running IIS. So, you'll have to create a Web service that can consume the data you want to pass to it. Once the Web Service is created, find the new Web Service in Access (using the toolkit), and use the exposed methods as needed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140260%28v=office.10%29.aspx